# Firebase returning undefined for single field

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

Branching from a firebase quickstart template for a simple blogger (source: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/database)

I am writing data to the firebase DB successfully, and am able to pull and display all values in an HTML element, bar one value which has started returning undefined, despite having data in DB / .json.

Code sample for writing the data to the DB:

```
    // [START write_fan_out]
function writeNewPost(uid, username, picture, title, body) {
    var postedDate = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    // A post entry.
    var postData = {
        author: username,
        uid: uid,
        body: body,
        title: title,
        authorPic: picture,
        posted: postedDate,
    };

    // Get a key for a new Post.
    var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;

    // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
    var updates = {};
    updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
    //updates['/category/' + title + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

    //updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
// [END write_fan_out]
```

This works without issue. Example of the data written in .json format:

```
    "-KTmYfts6vYEjyjo1rvk" : {
  "author" : "Nathan",
  "authorPic" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/photo.jpg",
  "body" : "Time: 6:00pm\nDuration: 35 seconds\nRecovery: 60 seconds\n",
  "posted" : "11/10/2016",
  "title" : "Seizure",
  "uid" : "rB4n3ELLnFUCWHztHLGA4mVeSHm1"
}
```

This is correct data as the date is shown under the "posted" tag.
The code for rendering on the page is:

```
function createPostElement(postId, title, text, author, authorId, authorPic, posted) {
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

var html =
    '<div class="post mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col ' +
    'mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-desktop mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing">' +
    '<div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">' +
    '<div class="mdl-card__title dark-purple mdl-color-text--white">' +
    '<h4 class="mdl-card__title-text"></h4>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="header">' +
    '<div>' +
    '<div class="avatar"></div>' +
    '<div class="username mdl-color-text--black"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="date"></div>' +
    '<div class="text"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

// Create the DOM element from the HTML.
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;
var postElement = div.firstChild;
componentHandler.upgradeElements(postElement.getElementsByClassName('mdl-textfield')[0]);

// Set values.
postElement.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].innerText = text;
postElement.getElementsByClassName('mdl-card__title-text')[0].innerText = title;
postElement.getElementsByClassName('date')[0].innerText = posted;
postElement.getElementsByClassName('username')[0].innerText = author || 'Anonymous';
postElement.getElementsByClassName('avatar')[0].style.backgroundImage = `url("${authorPic || './silhouette.jpg'}")`;
```

This is working for every field but "posted" which returns 'undefined' despite having data in the DB.

Apologies for the blocks of code, each of the write, DB data and present all tie in to why this isn't working, I assume...

I have tested the "posted" data in another field and it displays correctly. I have also used another fields data in the 'date' div which also works correctly. 
so somewhere in the pulling from the DB to writing on the page I have broken it.

Comment: We're missing the code that calls `()`, which means we can't see how you look up the value of `posted`. It would also help if you reduce the problem a bit. If only `posted` is giving problems, you can remove most of the other properties and reduce the code that we have to consider (and potentially find the problem while reducing the code). See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for the advice, apologies for the mass blocks. You were correct in that trimming down the code and viewing the call function I was able to find the `posted` field was not being retrieved correctly.

Comment: Good to hear that you got it sorted Nathan.